# Are there any disadvantages to wrapper types besides performance?

Tags: java, database, wrapper

In my line of work I'm mostly working on business applications that have a lot of database code. I don't usually write number crunching scientific logic.

This makes me wonder - would it be a good idea to always use wrapper types in my entity classes? I've found myself frequently converting primitives to wrappers. On the contrary I can't think of a case where I couldn't do without a primitive.

If I declared the fields in my entities to be wrappers the data read from db would be automatically mapped onto these by my persistence layer, thus saving me the trouble of having to create them manually.

Some things only come through experience hence I'm asking you folks, has anyone tried going with this approach? Are there any problems with it?

*I'm not concerned about performance but am asking this from good practice/architecture point of view.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrappers vs Primitives

Pros

- can be used with generics
- supports many additional methods.

Cons

- uses more cpu
- uses more memory
- implies the value can be `null`
- is longer to type in some cases.

Comment: Since cpu and memory is none of my concern, and db values can obviously be null, I guess that's a nod for the all wrappers approach. Yes?

Comment: If it can be `null`, using a wrapper is likely to be a better choice. I prefer to use primitives where possible, but not in this case.

Comment: BTW My point about longer names seems trivial except the time it takes to write `Integer` instead of `int` can cost in your time 1000x more than the cost of the memory difference.  However, the cost of writing confusing code is usually much, much higher, so make it as simple and clear as you can.

Comment: Thanks. What made me ask this question was the fact that Ruby has no primitives only wrappers. I wish java had shorter names for them.

Comment: Ideally the compiler could have optimise the use of primitives vs wrappers so its not something you should need to worry about. I would add a keyword or annotation which says whether a value can be `null` or not. (I would make variables not `null` able by default)

Comment: *"I would add a keyword or annotation which says whether a value can be null or not."* I don't get this. You mean like a marker annotation to clarify the intent of the code or do you mean an annotation based constraint at the persistence layer?

Comment: The constraint would be in Java whether you have persistence or not. Any reference can be `null` whether this is desirable or not. If you switch on an `enum` for example, you might imagine you have handled every case as you have a `case` for every value, but the reference could also be `null` which you might have to check for outside the switch.