# Java: Should I use float or Float?

Tags: java, object, floating-point, primitive-types

My colleague told me that I should use `float` whenever possible to reduce the object creation and increase the performance. Java silently converts `float` to `Float` (this needs some computational power) whenever necessary. So it seems to me that the only need for `Float` is when one needs to use the object `Float` very often instead of its primitive.

When looking at `java.awt.Color`, it is using the `Float`, perhaps unnecessarily.

When would one need to prefer `Float` over `float` in Java?

Comment: Use Float when using Generics, and when you want the float to hold an extra value (null).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12640826/139010 http://stackoverflow.com/q/8419860/139010

Comment: One typical situation is when you want to store your float in a collection: unless it is an array, you have to use Float.

Comment: "Generally, you should use primitive types unless you need an object for some reason..."  IMHO...

Comment: IMHO Neither. There is almost never a good use case for `float`.  You are better of using `double` or `Double` or BigDecimal.  The memory you save is rarely worth the loss of precision. (double is half a trillion times more precise)  You would prefer Float if you have an API which has to have Float.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **object** `Float` can be set to null to represent a value that is unknown.
The **primitive** `float` is guaranteed to have a value.

There is some overhead on the autoboxing, but this is negligible.  You still must allocate space for the primitive so there is nothing you gain there.

Comment: Float.NaN can also represent an unknown value.  A `Float` is 5-7x bigger than a `float`

Comment: @PeterLawrey source on the 5-7x larger

Comment: float is 4 bytes by definition.  A reference needs 4-8 bytes (32/64 bit references). An object header is 12 to 16-bytes (32/64 bit) and must be aligned to 8 bytes.  They are not directly comparable as a float alone doesn't use the heap and a Float is on the heap. So in terms of heap usage float: 0, Float is 16-24 bytes. Too many references to dig up ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey today i learned.

Comment: Here's a video from a Google Usergroup Meeting where this specific float vs Float topic is covered in the context of Android's animation framework, mostly regarding Garbage Collection issues https://youtu.be/wJYTBjMZJh0?t=11m20s This is presented by the guy working at Google on the animation framework (Chet Haase)